# ECMA script Error: The collection has not been initialized

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am getting this error while using querying a SharePoint list (2010) through JQuery 
**The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.**

I am looping through all the options in html select element and querying SharePoint list.

```
     $("#IdeasStatus option").each(function()
    {
        statusCount = statusCount + 1;
        lstStatus.push($(this).val());            
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < lstStatus.length; i++) {
         *****Some Code*********
       retItems = spList.getItems(caml);                       
       spContext.load(retItems);
      spContext.executeQueryAsync(onCategorySuccess, onCategoryFail);}
```

I am getting error in below function

```
    function onCategorySuccess(sender, args) {
    executionCount++;
    $('input[id$=hidChartParam1]').val($('input[id$=hidChartParam1]').attr('value') + ',' + status);
    $('input[id$=hidChartParam2]').val($('input[id$=hidChartParam2]').attr('value') + ',' + retItems.get_count());
    if (executionCount == statusCount) {
        FillPieChart();
    }
}
```

error is thrown while fetching the count **retItems.get_count()** which I believe is because same variable name (retItems) is used while looping and making multiple async calls?

Please suggest what shall I do?

Comment: Please suggest.. I haven't found any solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have You call `onCategorySuccess` elsewhere? It looks like you are in the `onCategorySuccess` before actually fill in `retItems` with values.

Answer (score 0):

i believe that at some point before calling spList.getItems you should load to the context the spList