# sharepoint javascript collection not initialized error

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

I have a strange problem. It occurs totally randomly, I have no idea why and in what circumstances it comes.

Details: I want to get the members of a Group with the `executeQueryAsync` function. In the callback the `userEnumerator = users.getEnumerator();` row throws this exception:
**The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.**

There is no other async code running. I dont know if this important, but this only happens if this is running at page load.

I insert this code with an `XML Viewer` webpart.

```
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current(),

    groups = ctx.get_web().get_siteGroups(),
    group = groups.getById(6),
    users = group.get_users();

    ctx.load(group);
    ctx.load(users);

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        var userEnumerator,
            user;

         $("#members-select").empty();

         userEnumerator = users.getEnumerator();
         while (userEnumerator.moveNext()) {
              user = userEnumerator.get_current();
              $("#members-select").append('<option>' + user.get_title() + '</option>');
          }
    });
```

Thanks, if anyone knows and shares any information about this.
I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022963/ecma-script-error-the-collection-has-not-been-initialized) question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a slightly different approach of loading group users. 
Since Group client object exposes [Users](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.group.users%28v=office.15%29.aspx) property, you could load Group with Users property initialized like this:

```
ctx.load(group,'Users');
```

Example:

```
(function(){
  var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var groups = ctx.get_web().get_siteGroups();
  var group = groups.getById(6);

  ctx.load(group,'Users');
  ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {

       var users = group.get_users();
       var e = users.getEnumerator();
       while (e.moveNext()) {
        var user = e.get_current();
        console.log(user.get_title());
       }

     },
     function(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());    
     }
   );

})();
```

Key points:

- Error handler was added for `SP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks like its working. :) I will test it throughout the day and if the problem does not show up, I will accept your answer.